# Hive Beeline Authorization failure in Kerberos Authenticated Cluster configured with Blob Storage

Tags: azure, hadoop, hive, azure-blob-storage, kerberos

I have created kerberos authenticated secure cluster configured with azure blob storage.
Hive and metastore db services where started but while connecting beeline using keytab getting authorization issue for blob storage.

Following are the error message:

Error: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1
from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. MetaException(message:java.security
.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=hive_AzureClu, path="wasb://mys
eccontainer@xxxxxxxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/user/hive/warehouse":user_name:supergroup:drwxr-xr-x) (state=08S01,code=1)

Configuration in core-site.xml for blob storage

```
<property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
  <value>wasb://myseccontainer@storageaccountname.blob.core.windows.net/</value>
  </property>
 <property>
    <name>fs.azure.account.key.storageaccountname.blob.core.windows.net</name>
    <value>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</value>
  </property>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you post more details for what you were doing? Your configuration or other key content.

Comment: Hi Peter, I have updated the configuration changes for blob storage in kerberos cluster.

Comment: It seems you have created the warehouse directory with username supergroup but then you are trying to write to it with hive_AzureClu. But as you see this user does not have access to writing that file (755). This is expected.